# How to wrapping text content when using datafram.to_html()

Tags: python, dataframe, smtp, text-to-html

There's text content wrapping in my excel(one grid),just like this:

```
"2022/10/17: Update detail in 10/18
2022/10/18: Keep tracking 1 week. Check point: 10/25"
```

when I read it with pandas(pd.read_excel), it becomes:

```
"2022/10/17: Update detail in 10/18\n2022/10/18: Keep tracking 1 week. Check point: 10/25"
```

so when I transfer the dataframe with df.to_hdml(), (I want to use SMTP to send the content),it becomes:

```
</thead> 
<tbody>
 <tr> 
  <td>2022/10/17: Update detail in 10/18\n2022/10/18: Keep tracking 1 week. Check point: 10/25</td>
```

The '\n' show as text in the content instead of line wrap.
Here I call help to find out solution, to wrap text content in the html td content. thank you in advance.

I've created one function:

```
def wrap_words(word):
    words = word.split('\n') 
    word_list =[]     
    for i in range(1,len(words)):
        word_list.append(words[i])
    wording = '\n'.join(word_list)
    return wording
```

but it doesn't work.

also
`.apply(lambda x: str(x).replace('\n','<br />'))`
dosen't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace `\n` with `<br>` - [Html new line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br)

```
print(df.to_html().replace("\\n","<br>") )
```

Html page table #

[image]

Comment: thanks, it works. replace after df.to_html instead of before transferring.